# How do I (can I?) get the exit status from a command?

Tags: python, ssh, twisted, twisted.conch

Using `twisted.conch`, I'm working with the following `SSHChannel` implementation, which is fed a command to run when instantiated:

```
class CommandChannel(channel.SSHChannel):
    name = 'session'

    def __init__(self, command, *args, **kwargs):
        channel.SSHChannel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.command = command

    def channelOpen(self, data):
        d = self.conn.sendRequest(
            self, 'exec', common.NS(self.command), wantReply=True)
        d.addCallback(self._gotResponse)

    def _gotResponse(self, _):
        self.conn.sendEOF(self)
        self.loseConnection()

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        log.msg('dataReceived: data=%r' % data)

    def extReceived(self, dataType, data):
        log.msg('extReceived: dataType=%r, data=%r' % (dataType, data))

    def closed(self):
        reactor.stop()
```

To this I'm feeding a shell command that should be returning some sort of exit status.  Can I read what that exit status is?  I had hoped `extReceived` might be my way in, but it doesn't look like it.

In my logs I see this, which seems like it should be a hint where to look, but I'm not sure how to follow said hint:

```
2013-04-05 10:39:37-0400 [SSHChannel session (0) on SSHService ssh-connection
    on CommandTransport,client] unhandled request for exit-status
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two extra callbacks you might want to implement for this.  These are callbacks on the channel, so you're pretty close already.

The first is `request_exit_status`.  Once you implement this, Conch will no longer log that the `exit-status` request is unhandled.  Here's an example implementation:

```
def request_exit_status(self, data):
    """
    When the server sends the command's exit status, record it for later
    delivery to the protocol.

    @param data: The network-order four byte representation of the exit
        status of the command.
    @type data: L{bytes}
    """
    (status,) = unpack('>L', data)
    if status != 0:
        self._reason = ProcessTerminated(status, None, None)
```

The second is `request_exit_signal`.  `exit-signal` is sent instead of `exit-status` if the command is terminated by a signal.  Here's an example implementation:

```
def request_exit_signal(self, data):
    """
    When the server sends the command's exit status, record it for later
    delivery to the protocol.

    @param data: The network-order four byte representation of the exit
        signal of the command.
    @type data: L{bytes}
    """
    (signal,) = unpack('>L', data)
    self._reason = ProcessTerminated(None, signal, None)
```

The general pattern here is that when `SSHChannel` receives a request for *foo* it will try to call `request_foo` with the bytes making up the request.